# Selecting group in accordion list

Tags: angularjs

I just started with Angular and I got a code sample from codepen [Accordion List](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz)

I'm trying to use my data in the html like this:

```
<div class="group">
  <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}"></ion-item>
  <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}"></ion-item>
  <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
```

and the JS is set like this:

```
angular.module('my-app',['ionic'])

.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
    name: "Basic Info",
    items: [1,2,3]},
    {
      name: "Torso Measures",
      items: [1,2,3]},
    {
      name: "Extra measures",
      items: [1,2,3,4,5],
    }
  ];

  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };

});
```

The problem is that whenever I click in 1 group, all of them expand / collapse. In JS / jQuery I'd pass an id but I think there is an "angular way" to do it. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo **without `ng-repeat`** [here](http://codepen.io/smallyin/pen/reRggz?editors=1010).

Demo **with `ng-repeat`** [here](http://codepen.io/smallyin/pen/BKbgWj?editors=1010).

**Why your code cant work:**
Since you didn't use `ng-repeat` in your markup, **`group`** in these places

```
<ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}"></ion-item>
  <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
```

are both **`undefined`**.

You need init the `group` variable for `toggleGroup(group)`,`isGroupShown(group)` and should be different name if used **twice** in same scope.Update your html:

```
    <div class="group" ng-init="groupid1=1">
      <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(groupid1)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(groupid1)}"></ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(groupid1)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label></label>
          <input>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <div class="group" ng-init="groupid2=2">
      <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(groupid2)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(groupid2)}"></ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(groupid2)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label></label>
          <input>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
```

However,By **using `ng-repeat`**, you can use your html with wrapped like this:

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="group in groups track by $index">
      <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}"></ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label></label>
          <input>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
```

It should works.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to define my groups in the controller section? So I could use the `group in groups`

Comment: You're actually **doing** define groups in controller section by this statement `$scope.groups = [{...},{...},{...}]`.

Comment: How could I replace it then? Sorry. I'm new at this and there is a lot of information that confuses instead of help.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that all your groups expand on click is probably because you have (in your snipet of code) two divs that uses the same group model.

I am talking about the  group given in to your toggle function :

```
ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
```

In the tutorial, the writter uses an ng-repeat directive to generate his divs

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
```

this line goes in groups and take each item in groups member into a new group model. This could be why your accordions all expands,(and probably have the same content all of them). Could you give us a litle more co

If you want to use bootstrap accordion I can advise you to look at  [Angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), an Angular module to replace bootstrap.js and make the same things in an Angular way (using directives, databinding....).